# Intercept Exceptions in @BeforeEach for Handling before @AfterEach

Tags: junit5

In JUnit 5, there is a difficulty in handling exceptions that occur in the @BeforeEach method and an inability to intercept them before calling the @AfterEach method, even if an exception occurred in the test.
The @AfterTestExecutionCallback extension allows handling exceptions that occur during the execution of the @Test method (@Test method). However, this extension doesn't work for the @BeforeEach method, thus providing no means to intercept exceptions in this setup phase.

I have a concrete example demonstrating the issue with my code and its output. You can find it here: [Code Example and Output]:

LogsWatcher.kt

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.*
import org.junit.jupiter.api.fail


open class LogsWatcher : TestWatcher, BeforeEachCallback, AfterEachCallback, BeforeTestExecutionCallback,
    AfterTestExecutionCallback {

    override fun testFailed(context: ExtensionContext, cause: Throwable?) {
        failedLogs(context, object {}.javaClass.enclosingMethod.name)
        super.testFailed(context, cause)
    }

    open fun failedLogs(context: ExtensionContext?, methodName: String) {
        println("$methodName started")
        val testFailed = context?.executionException?.isPresent ?: fail("Test has no context")

        if (testFailed) {
            println("   $methodName: failed")

        }
    }

    override fun beforeEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        failedLogs(context, object {}.javaClass.enclosingMethod.name)
    }

    override fun afterEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        failedLogs(context, object {}.javaClass.enclosingMethod.name)
    }

    override fun beforeTestExecution(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        failedLogs(context, object {}.javaClass.enclosingMethod.name)
    }

    override fun afterTestExecution(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        failedLogs(context, object {}.javaClass.enclosingMethod.name)
    }
}
```

MyTest.kt

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith

@ExtendWith(LogsWatcher::class)
class MyTest {
    @BeforeEach
    fun preCondition(){
        println("@BeforeEach start")
        Assertions.assertTrue(false)
        println("@BeforeEach stop")
    }

    @Test
    fun myTest(){
        println("Test start")
        Assertions.assertTrue(false)
        println("Test stop")
    }

    @AfterEach
    fun postCondition1(){
        println("@AfterEach 1")
    }

    @AfterEach
    fun postCondition2(){
        println("@AfterEach 2")
    }
}
```

Output if fail in @BeforeEach

```
beforeEach started
@BeforeEach start
@AfterEach 1
@AfterEach 2
afterEach started
   afterEach: failed
testFailed started
   testFailed: failed
```

Output if fail in @Test

```
beforeEach started
@BeforeEach start
@BeforeEach stop
beforeTestExecution started
Test start
afterTestExecution started
   afterTestExecution: failed
@AfterEach 1
@AfterEach 2
afterEach started
   afterEach: failed
testFailed started
   testFailed: failed
```

There is no answer to my [issue](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/3411) in the official repository. Maybe someone knows a workaround to solve the problem.

UPD. There was an answer to my [issue](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/3411), where I should search LifecycleMethodExecutionExceptionHandler, when I search I will update the post.

Comment: Have you looked at https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.5.2/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/InvocationInterceptor.html ?

Comment: Please don't link to your code. Links can break, making the question impossible to understand and useless for others with similar problems. [Edit] your question and include a [mcve] here. See also [ask]